# Dynamic LIKE queries with python 2.7 and MySQLdb

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python, dynamicquery

It is my understanding that SQL injection is, in general, bad. And that's fine becuase as described in PEP 249, you can use placeholders to protect against most generic injections. However I see nothing that speaks to how to make queries involving LIKE dynamic.

My situation specifically is I have an ajax call that's ran on input change to a Name field. The result being my query results get filtered `WHERE table.name LIKE name_var` as a simple representation. Obviously directly subbing in the name_var into the query is horrifyingly dangerous, and some of you may have even had a small stroke from seeing that. But how do I make this safe and dynamic? Do I build my own parser? Does MySQLdb have some built in functionality to also handle this? I can't seem to find much useful info so I'd appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes MySQLdb can do this.

```
sql = """SELECT ... WHERE t.name LIKE %s"""
cur = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
cur.execute(sql, (name_var,))
```

If you want wildcards so you can search for substrings, you can do that in the SQL expression:

```
sql = """SELECT ... WHERE t.name LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%')"""
cur = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
cur.execute(sql, (name_var,))
```

Or you can do it to the Python variable before passing it as a parameter:

```
sql = """SELECT ... WHERE t.name LIKE %s"""
cur = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
name_var_with_wildcards = '%{0}%'.format(name_var)
cur.execute(sql, (name_var_with_wildcards,))
```

If your name_var may contain literal LIKE wildcards `%` and `_`, you need to escape them:

```
sql = """SELECT ... WHERE t.name LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%')"""
cur = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
name_var_escaped = re.sub(r'([_%])', r'\\\1', name_var)
cur.execute(sql, (name_var_escaped,))
```

Comment: Oh awesome, I figured I could do something to that effect but was having no luck. I'll dive down that rabbit whole and see where it gets me. Thanks!